# Regular Expression pattern matching equal 0's and 1's

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match all strings of length less than 5 , where the number of 0's and number of 1's are equal containing only 0's and 1's

I am not able to figure out a pattern to match it.
this is what I have come up till now

`/01|10|1100|1010|1001|0011|0101|0110/`

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The only trouble is that the first alternative that matches wins, and others are not tried. Put longer alternatives before shorter ones.

Comment: But I am trying to find a pattern, these are just the possibilities, am not quite sure how to convert these into a pattern

Comment: Unique permutations are the antithesis of patterns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have covered all the possible alternatives in your regex, you could just wrap it inside anchors for start and end of string:

```js
const strings = ['01', '011', '101', '1100', '100101', '', '1000', '0111', '1010'];
console.log(strings.map(s => /^(01|10|1100|1010|1001|0011|0101|0110)$/.test(s)));
```

That is the brute force approach. I think the best you can do with a pattern is this:

```js
const strings = ['01', '011', '101', '1100', '100101', '', '1000', '0111', '1010'];
console.log(strings.map(s => /^((01|10){1,2}|0011|1100)$/.test(s)));
```

Comment: I could, but then it becomes long, it would be better with a pattern

Comment: will go with this if I don't find  a pattern

Comment: Hi @DipeshDesai, I've added a pattern solution as well. It's a bit of an improvement...

Answer (score 1):

Just want to point out that the question of matching a given number of equal '0's and '1's between two arbitrary limits lends itself to a rather interesting solution. It isn't possible in JavaScript regex specifically (at least, not as far as I know), since nested references aren't supported. However, here's a method that works in most other flavours:

```
^(?:(?=(?=\2?+1*0)(\1?+0*1))(?=(\2?+1*0))){1,10}+(?=\1(?!0*1))\2[1]*$
```

[Check it out on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/N9lewQ/1/)

That `{1,10}` defines the limits on the number of '0's and '1's, so for the original question, this would be `{1,2}`.

This works by simultaneously accumulating groups containing the next occurrences of '0' and '1', and checking afterwards that no new occurrences exist afterwards.

Comment: `^(?:(?=(\1?+1*01*($)?))(?=(\3?+0*10*($)?))){1,10}?\2\4.*` - [demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/N9lewQ/2) - [same basic technique](http://www.drregex.com/2017/11/lookahead-quantification-utterly-loopy.html) but shorter and simpler. Note that these won't work in Perl either, because it apparently applies the same ["no empty optional"](https://github.com/Davidebyzero/RegexMathEngine/issues/1) rule as JavaScript.

Comment: `^(?:1*01*(?<=(?=((?>\1?)0*10*($)?))^.*))+\2$` ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY/BasMwDIbvfQrP9GBnabB7bOZmUDYYtAy2wi6l4KVKa3CcYjldR@izZ05LD5MOkn59QlKJk7Lx0DtdAx51CeTzFwPUXYvG7ckaziH7gH1rtX85Hz0gmsZhXlqNSOoOgw6mJKfG7MhKG0cY707aE1TPtN@yYiYTIRNWPClWKMaK@UYWXCRSJGzMC863WcL542Y67mk@zHnl4IfEhXBmmH223xh8vIPJFLMluH04TKY8vfbfj2E4JVs09dFY2PH8xhKbV41nxgVSKZEzqxYRayzEP/RuaRwwzh@Ua20EleSdqVg1F/xOfXkT4Ibl/zRGO3Hp5IWmPnvDlQ7lgVle0LVvYUYIndFXbTGmNLU8v0TrpRhJIUdCSilEDHe/KlGKYSiHbHQV7oSQfw "C# (.NET Core) – Try It Online")) - .NET regex with no arbitrary length limit, using variable-length lookbehind.

Comment: `^(?=(?>(?'z'0)|1)*$)(?>(?'-z'1)|0)*$(?(z).)` ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY9Ra8IwEIDf/RVZGJgbtSR7tNQOZIOBMpiDvQ2yetVAmkoudc7qb@9SxYflHu7uyxdyV9KkbDz2TtdIO10iW/1SwLprybgN@8BDSN9x01rtnw87j0SmcZSVVhOxuqOggynZvjFrttTGMQHdXntG@RPvv0SRi2ImivFxLOGk4OEerv3kOFZwkhGIQhwhhZ5nwzOfO/xh8T88CEpX7TcFH8cQKqF0gW4TtpNHSC73b7swTJLOm3pnLK4hu7rMZlXjhXGBVbnMhM3nUWssxjX0emEcCoC73LU2irmCzlSimkm4WZ/eBLxq2T8meCfPnTrzxKevtNSh3AoLBf/wLU4Z41P@oi3FkicWsnM8vZIjJdVIKqWkjOkWFxJRTEM7VKMLuBlS/QE "C# (.NET Core) – Try It Online")) - .NET regex with no arbitrary length limit, using balanced groups.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know.

But here's how you could do it without using a Regular Expression:

```
var arrayOfStrings = ["11111", "22222", "12345", "00000", "111111", "11002", "10222"];
for(var i=0; i<arrayOfStrings.length; i++)
{
    if(arrayOfStrings[i].length <= 5 && arrayOfStrings[i].split('1').length > 1 && arrayOfStrings[i].split('1').length == arrayOfStrings[i].split('0').length)
    {
        // Only prints "11002", "10222"
        console.log(arrayOfStrings[i]);
    }
}
```

**Find Strings that are:**
 Of length <= 5, 
 Have at least 1 '1' 
 Have an equal number of 1's and 0's.

Comment: I am using only 0's and 1's. And I need a regEx Match. That's the requirment

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this?

```
const check = (s) => {
    const length = s.length;
    if(length % 2 || length > 4) return false;

    const count0 = s.match(/[0]/g).length || 0;
    const count1 = s.match(/[1]/g).length || 0;
    return count0 == count1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best I could come up with...

```
/^1100|0011|10(10|01)?|01(01|10)?$/
```

... or alternatively ...

```
/^0(011|1(01|10)?)|1(100|0(10|01)?)$/
```